# How to limit query results to exact group match

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, subquery

I have a table like the following:

```
user  | item
-------------
   X  | Apple
   X  | Orange
   X  | Pear
   Y  | Orange
   Y  | Pear
   Z  | Apple
   Z  | Orange
```

My goal is to have 3 search options: `ANY`, `ALL` (At Least), `EXACT`

Where

- **ANY** returns a list of users who have at least one item searched for, so searching for "Apple" - ANY would return X,Z, searching for "Apple, Orange" - ANY would return X,Y,Z
- **ALL** returns a list of users who have all items searched for, so searching for "Apple" - ALL would return X,Z, searching for "Apple, Orange" - ALL would return X,Z
- **EXACT** returns a list of users who have all items searched for and no other items, , so searching for "Apple" - EXACT would return no results,  searching for "Apple, Orange" - EXACT would return Z

I have the first two worked out:

`ANY`

```
SELECT user FROM users_items WHERE item IN ($item_array);
```

`ALL`

```
SELECT user FROM users_items WHERE item IN ($item_array) 
GROUP BY user HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item) = $item_search_count;
```

But I can't figure out how to do the exact search. The best I can come up with is:

```
SELECT user FROM users_items WHERE item IN ($item_array) AND
user NOT IN (
     SELECT user FROM users_items WHERE item NOT IN ($item_array)
)
GROUP BY user HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item) = $item_search_count;
```

This didn't work at first because in the real data set, either user or item could be null but when I updated it to:

```
SELECT user FROM users_items WHERE item IN ($item_array) AND
user NOT IN (
     SELECT user FROM users_items WHERE item NOT IN ($item_array) 
     AND user IS NOT NULL AND item IS NOT NULL
)
GROUP BY user HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item) = $item_search_count;
```

This worked, but the query is really slow.

Is there a better way to query for "all items that match set, exclude items that don't match set"?

Comment: I guess you meant `GROUP BY user` in all those queries.

Comment: What indexes do you have in the table?

Comment: @ypercube - I did mean `GROUP BY user`, thanks.  In the real table, both the item and the user are foreign keys, neither indexed, and I don't have control over this. The table represents products sold, the item would be the catalog number and the user would be the customer id, but items can exist in the table where it was not based on an item in the catalog (rare, but not minuscule) and the item could be tied to a list that hasn't yet been tied to a customer, so in either case, the item or user in my example would be null.

Comment: @ajreal - `orange, apple`, assuming no case-sensitivity should return the same as `Apple, Orange`.  If the order of the list were set in stone, I think it would actually be easier.  But the idea is that we want to find all users who have both `apple` and `orange`, no more, no less.

Comment: Well then, the slowness is explained by the lack of indexes. A compound index on `(user, item)` would help a lot.

Comment: If the user or the item can be null, the table is no normalized. Fix your table structure first - why do you store data for things that have no entry?

Comment: @DavidManheim - 1) I didn't have the privilidge of fixing the table structure, which was part of the challenge/need for such an approach. 2) The user or the item can be null, but not both. And as I recall, the db/tables had more going on then those two fields. The idea was to be able to return results where both are true or either are true in a user interface without having to write multiple queries.  But usually the answer to any db problem is to fix structure.  You can never be too normal.

Comment: I've been forced to work with bad data structures before - it sucks. And I think I agree with your point that databases should be normal (people don't have to.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the magic [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT user
FROM (
    SELECT user, group_concat(item) as items
    from user_items
    group by 1) x
WHERE items = 'Apple,Orange';
```

Note: The list of items you're searching for (eg `'Apple,Orange'`) must be in alphabetic order

Comment: Does an Order By on the subquery order the results of the `group_concat`?

Comment: Oh, and I think I ran into a column size limit when I tried group_concat, not for this specific part, but one of the other bits I already worked out.

Answer (score 0):

The following works, and should solve your size problem.
But it could be slow, just try it with your real data.

```
Select 
    User 
FROM 
    users_items 
WHERE 
    User NOT IN
    (
        SELECT
            users.User
        FROM 
            users_items AS users
        JOIN 
            users_items AS users2 ON users.User = users2.User
        WHERE
            users2.Item NOT IN ('Apple','Orange')
        GROUP BY 
            users.User
    )
GROUP BY 
    User
```