# MySQL Select Where In Many to Many

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I'm having trouble with a SQL query. My schema describes a many to many relationship between articles in the `articles` table and categories in the `categories` table - with the intermediate table `article_category` which has an `id`, `article_id` and `category_id` field.

I want to select all articles which only have the categories with id `1` and `2`. Unfortunately this query will also select any articles which have those categories in addition to any others.

For example, this is a sample output from the SQL (**with categories shown for descriptive purposes**). You can see that while the query selected the article with id of `10`, it also selected the article with an id of `11` despite having one extra category.

```
+-------+------------+
| id    | categories |
+-------+------------+
| 10    | 1,2        |
| 11    | 1,2,3      |
+-------+------------+
```

This is the output that I want to achieve from selecting articles with only categories `1`and `2`.

```
+-------+------------+
| id    | categories |
+-------+------------+
| 10    | 1,2        |
+-------+------------+
```

Likewise, this is the output what I want to achieve from selecting articles with only categories `1`, `2` and `3`.

```
+-------+------------+
| id    | categories |
+-------+------------+
| 11    | 1,2,3      |
+-------+------------+
```

This is the SQL I have written. What am I missing to achieve the above?

```
SELECT articles.id
FROM articles
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM article_category
    WHERE articles.id = article_id AND category_id IN (1,2)
    GROUP BY article_id
)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Look the following question. Looks like the same problem to me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468117/how-to-limit-query-results-to-exact-group-match/23359672#23359672

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want more than just the article's id:

```
SELECT a.id
      ,a.other_stuff
  FROM articles a
  JOIN article_category ac
    ON ac.article_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ac.category_id ORDER BY ac.category_id SEPARATOR ',') = '1,2'
```

If all you want is the article's id then try this:

```
SELECT article_id
  FROM article_category 
GROUP BY article_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category_id ORDER BY category_id SEPARATOR ',') = '1,2'
```

See it in action at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d213/4

Should also add that the advantage of this approach is that it can support the checking of any number of categories without having to change the query. Just make '1,2' a string variable and change what gets passed into the query. So, you could just as easily search for articles with categories 1, 2, and 7 by passing a string of '1,2,7'. No additional joins are needed.

Comment: I don't want to be rude but how's that different from my answer?

Comment: several differences. 1) no WHERE EXISTS. 2) no sub-select. 3) no assumption that category_id's aren't repeated (probably a safe assumption but DISTINCT eliminates it). 4) no assumption that category_id's will be in ascending sequence in the database (ORDER BY eliminates that assumption). 5) IF article id is all that's required, no JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

You can left join `category_id` on `category.id` and then [GROUP_CONCAT](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/) to get all categories, like you wrote in explanation (1st table) and than using `HAVING` match with any set you like ( '1,2' from example)

also with that approach you can easily make this query dynamic with php or any other language

```
SELECT articles.id
FROM articles
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.id) AS grp
    FROM article_category
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = article_category.category_id
    WHERE articles.id = article_id
    GROUP BY article_id
    HAVING grp = '1,2'
)
```

Comment: This could probably use an explanation :-).

Answer (score 1):

Please Use Below Query You can do the Thing by Using Simple Query.

```
   SELECT a.id, a.name
    FROM articles a, categories c, articles_categories ac 
    WHERE
    a.id = ac.article_id AND c.id = ac.category_id 
    AND c.id = 1 OR c.id = 2;
```

**NOTE**- If You have Many to many Relationship between two Tables Remove ID from the article_category table and make composite primary key Using article_id and category_id.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I like to approach these queries using `group by` and `having`.  Here is an example:

```
select ac.article_id
from article_category ac
group by ac.article_id
having sum(case when category_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when category_id = 1 then 2 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause is testing for the presence of one of the categories.

I find that this approach is the most flexible for answering many different types of "set-within-sets" problems.

EDIT:

A slight variation on the above might be easier to generate:

```
having sum(category_id in (1, 2, 3)) = count(*) and
       count(*) = 3
```

This will work assuming there are no duplicates in the data.  You need to update the `3` to be the number of items in the `in` list.

Comment: How easy will this be for instances with more than two categories? I need to be able to generate this query dynamically using a script.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson . . . You simply need to add another condition to the `having` clause.  The advantage of this approach is that it can flexibly describe both inclusion and exclusion criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, something like:

```
select distinct article_id from article_cathegory 
      where category_id in (1,2)
minus 
select distinct article_id from article_cathegory 
      where category_id not in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like simple solution for this could be the following:

```
SELECT 
    ac.article_id
    , SUM(ac.category_id IN (1, 2)) AS nb_categories
    , COUNT(ac.category_id) AS nb_all_categories
FROM
    article_categories ac
GROUP BY
    ac.article_id
HAVING
    nb_categories=2 AND nb_all_categories=2
```

Here I count how many required categories we have and also count how many categories we have in total. We only need exactly 2 categories, so both required and total should be equal to 2.

This is quite flexible and for adding more categories just change categories list and numbers in HAVING statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT articles.id
FROM articles
INNER JOIN articles_category ac ON articles.id = ac.article_id
WHERE articles.id IN (
     SELECT ac1.article_id
     FROM article_category ac1
     WHERE ac1.category_id = 1;
     )
AND ac.article_id = 2;
AND articles.id NOT IN (
     SELECT ac2.article_id
     FROM article_category ac2
     WHERE ac2.category_id NOT IN (1, 2)
     )
```

Far from the prettiest one I have written.

Basically, it limits first by ID that have a category id of 1, then it makes sure the records have a category of 2 as well, finally, it makes sure that it does not have any other categories

Answer (score 0):

to help just without changing your query very much, i think the logic has a bug. you dont want articles where a categegory 1,2 exists. You need articles where does not exist categories different than 1 and 2.
thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server I would do it with an INTERSECT and an EXCEPT. In MySQL, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT article_id
  FROM article_category
  WHERE category_id=1
AND article_id IN
(SELECT article_id
  FROM article_category
  WHERE category_id=2)
AND article_id NOT IN
(SELECT article_id
  FROM article_category
  WHERE category_id NOT IN (1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this SQL query.

```
SELECT articles.id
FROM articles
WHERE articles.id in (
    SELECT *
    FROM article_category,articles
    WHERE article_category.articles.id = articles.article_id AND article_category.category_id IN (1,2)
)
```