# MYSQL many-to-many selection with AND condition

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231549/mysql-select-where-in-many-to-many) in stackoverflow, but it is not quite the problem I am facing right now. I could not find a better way of describing the required query, than the following:

***Select all the entries which have at least the property one AND property two AND ...***

Consider the following tables:

**users**

```
|  id  |  name  |
+------+--------+
|  1   |  john  |
+------+--------+
|  2   |  liu   |
+------+--------+
```

**sports**

```
|  id  |  user_id  |    sport   |
+------+-----------+------------+
|  1   |     1     |    swim    |
+------+-----------+------------+
|  2   |     1     |    run     |
+------+-----------+------------+
|  3   |     1     |  football  |
+------+-----------+------------+
|  4   |     1     |   volley   |
+------+-----------+------------+
|  5   |     2     |    swim    |
+------+-----------+------------+
|  6   |     2     |    run     |
+------+-----------+------------+
```

I would like to be able to make the following queries:

1. Select all users who only swim (straight forward)

Returns:

```
|  id  |  name  |
+------+--------+
|  1   |  john  |
+------+--------+
|  2   |  liu   |
+------+--------+
```

2. Select all users who can swim AND run

Returns:

```
|  id  |  name  |
+------+--------+
|  1   |  john  |
+------+--------+
|  2   |  liu   |
+------+--------+
```

3. Select all users who can swim AND run AND play football

Returns:

```
|  id  |  name  |
+------+--------+
|  1   |  john  |
+------+--------+
```

The number of sports should be dynamic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The number of items in the list can't really be "dynamic", at least not any more than any list of values can be.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN sports AS s ON s.user_id = u.id
WHERE s.sport IN ('football','run','swim')
GROUP B u.id, u.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sport) = 3
;
```

For longer/shorter lists, you just need to adjust the `3` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To check for all 3 you can do

```
select u.id, u.name
from users u
join sports s on s.user_id = u.id
group by u.id, u.name
having sum(sport = 'swim') > 0
   and sum(sport = 'run') > 0
   and sum(sport = 'football') > 0
```

Remove the ones from the query that you don't need for the other selects.